# Where can I find resources on creating a alarmManager and notification?

Tags: android

Can anyone point me a direction? I want to be able to set a Time and get notification. After some research, I think AlarmManager and notification builder are the right ones to use. Anyone know a good tutorials or a good book that teach you thoroughly on those?

Comment: goto google and search `alarmmanager and notification example, androd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful links that might help you

http://androidideasblog.blogspot.in/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html

http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html

http://maephv.blogspot.in/2011/08/android-alarmmanager-and-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

use below link, it explain all details of AlarmManager with example. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651